# Set table row background colour of td's with a specific value

Tags: jquery

I am trying to set the background colour of the table rows I find with a table column value equal to something in particular. So far I have what is below. My selector to grab all the columns with a specific value works. But then I can't figure out how to get the parent tr of all of the td's and set a css background colour on them.

```
var $tds = $("#myStoreStatus > tbody  > tr > td:nth-child(3):contains('Closed')");

$.each($tds, function(key, value) {               
    //alert($(this).text());        
    value.parent('tr').css( 'background-color','#FFFF99' );
});
```

Also if there is a way to do it without having to loop through all the tr's that would be nice.

thanks

Comment: There's no need for the loop. Just chain `.parent().css(...)` to the end of your `$tds` selector - [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/6fbyobkz/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$(this).parent('tr').css( 'background-color','#FFFF99' );`

Here is an example  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nMhmS/815/)